# CSS bootstrap - Set button pull-right over the input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I try to put my span .btn-search on the right over the input.
I add pull-right to my span but it's seems to not work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="search-row">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                         <input type="text" class="textbox">
                         <span class="btn-search pull-right"></span>
                         </input>
                    </div>
    </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5jQ/

Thanks,

Jérôme

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have asked to a friend and I have just omitted to set a relative position to the span.

Why, I don't know ...

Here's the solution

```
.btn-search {
width: 93px;
height: 49px;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
/* gradient overlay */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
/* gradient overlay */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
/* gradient overlay */
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
/* gradient overlay */
margin-bottom:2.5px;
}
.textbox {
width: 540px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
/* stroke */
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
/* drop shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
/* drop shadow */
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
/* drop shadow */
position:absolute;
}
#search-row div {
display: inline-block;
}
.col-centered-search {
width: 540px;
float: none !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="search-row" class="col-centered-search">
        <input type="text" class="textbox form-control" placeholder="Search"><span class="btn-search pull-right"></span>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5jQ/9/

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 3):

Try this out.  I've used it on a few different sites. I'm assuming you are using Bootstrap 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/zach57/wvu25/

```
<form id="search-form" class="navbar-form" method="get" role="search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>    
</form>
```

Comment: Inspire from your proposition I updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5jQ/3/ I have now a problem of index. My span is below the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `<span>`s inside of `<input>`s. To put it over the input, use `position: absolute` on the `span`. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5jQ/1/

Comment: I now need a right position of index. See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5jQ/3/

Comment: Hmm, there isn't an indexing problem on my original fiddle. Here's an update to your update of that other update. ;) http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5jQ/7/

Comment: Sorry, I don't receive alert from your new comment. Thanks for update.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your fiddle isn't saving so here is the solution I came up with.

CSS:

```
.btn-search {
    width: 93px;
    height: 49px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
    /* gradient overlay */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
    /* gradient overlay */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
    /* gradient overlay */
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #659900 -25%, #65ff00 125%);
    /* gradient overlay */
    margin-bottom:2.5px;
}
.textbox {
    width: 540px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    /* stroke */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
    /* drop shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
    /* drop shadow */
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
    /* drop shadow */
    position:absolute;
}
#search-row div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.col-centered-search {
    width: 540px;
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.glyphicon-search {
      postion: absolute;
      margin-left: -25px;  
      margin-top: 15px;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="search-row" class="col-centered-search">
            <input type="text" class="textbox form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-btn pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```